How to request more scope in facebook application after recent changes
I am not able to get list of scope from `App Review Requests` in facebook app review page due to recent change which implement Use Cases.
I want to add some scope - pages_manage_posts, pages_show_list, business_management, pages_manage_engagement, pages_read_engagement, read_insights etc to be added into my facebook application, previously we used to get Permissions and Features under app review page. Now I am not able to get list of scope from App Review Requests in facebook app review page due to recent change which implement Use Cases.
I am attaching application snapshot from old and new.
New app
OLD app
I am expecting way to add more scope to be added into new workflow using usecase but everytime i try to add new usecase there are none to add.
